# UI Automation switch window

Tags: c#, winapi, ui-automation

I've noticed that setforegroundwindow can be very flaky - no matter how you do it.

I've noticed that using UIAutomation, where possible, seems to improve things.

For example:

Getting the WindowPattern and using something like:

```
windowPattern.SetWindowVisualState( WindowVisualState.Normal );

windowPattern.SetWindowVisualState( WindowVisualState.Maximized );
```

Now my questions is:

How do I know whether I should make it maximized or normal.  The task manager, and dragon naturally speaking both seem to know how to do this.  If it was previous maximized, and then minimized, I'd like to maximize the window when I switch to it.  If it was previously not maximized, I'd like to make it "Normal".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SetFocus for AutomationElement didn't work.

From the following question:
[Get window state of another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065026/get-window-state-of-another-process)

I found that the GetPlacement api gave me what I needed:

```
     if ( (windowplacement.flags & WPF_RESTORETOMAXIMIZED) > 0 )
     {
        windowPattern.SetWindowVisualState( WindowVisualState.Maximized );
     }
     else
     {
        windowPattern.SetWindowVisualState( WindowVisualState.Normal );
     }
```

With this the window will restore to maximized if it was maximized and restore to normal if it was not maximized.

Answer (score 2):

You may use the WindowPattern to set window to foreground as follows:

```
var p =
 (WindowPattern)_w.AutomationElement.GetCurrentPattern(WindowPattern.Pattern);
p.SetWindowVisualState(WindowVisualState.Normal);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I misunderstood the question. I believe the key to doing what you want is to use the [AutomationElement.SetFocus()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.automationelement.setfocus.aspx) method.

Here's a basic example.

```
//I assume you already have some way of getting the window's handle
var wih = new System.Windows.Interop.WindowInteropHelper(window);
IntPtr hWnd = wih.Handle;

//get the automation element from the handle
var ae = AutomationElement.FromHandle(hWnd);

//this will bring the window into focus.
ae.SetFocus();
```

Comment: This is somewhat useful, but I would need to know what to pass in as the visualState to use.  So let's say I am making a task switch application.  I have the hwnd, and then the AutomationElement for a window that is currently minimized in the taskbar.  I don't know how to find if the window WAS previously in a maximized or a normal state.  So I wouldn't know whether I should pass in "Normal" or "Maximized" to this function.

Comment: @Derek I have updated my answer, and I think it does what you are looking for better. I did some very basic testing, and it seemed to work the same way that the "Switch To" worked in Task Manager.