# Process know whether it is behind another application

Tags: c#

**Got to do about the issue because I never know the right answer to my question.**

The problem is that even if I run codes that check it so it says that it is running normal and yet so is an application of it. I want in any way to recognize whether a program is over notepad.

**I've tried but it says it is running normal yet so is an application of it.
[Get window state of another process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065026/get-window-state-of-another-process)**

Need some code that detects if any application is over notepad.

```
Process[] p = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAWCi.png

It detects whether it lies behind another application.

I've tried a lot of different codes but all of them say the same thing to be running normally even if it is behind another application.

Comment: are you trying to figure out if the current application has the focus ?

Comment: @dotctor yes,, But you are linking to is not another process.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7162834/determine-if-current-application-is-activated-has-focus Has solved my problem thanks for the help. I did not know what it's called what I wanted.