# Determine if Windows 10 Touch Keyboard is Visible or Hidden

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, touch, virtual-keyboard

I am trying to find out if the windows 10 virtual touch keyboard is visible or not to know whether to open it or not from my application. THe following code has worked fine up until the latest Windows 10 update 15063 or possible the one right before it. Seems like Microsoft changed something with the window styles possibly but I can't figure it out.

```
    public static bool IsKeyboardVisible()
    {
        IntPtr keyboardHandle = GetKeyboardWindowHandle();
        // Specifies we wish to retrieve window styles.
        int GWL_STYLE = -16;

        //The window is disabled. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms632600(v=vs.85).aspx.
        UInt32 WS_VISIBLE =               0x10000000;
        UInt32 WS_DISABLED =              0x08000000;
        UInt32 WS_POPUP =                 0x80000000;


        bool visible = false;
        bool disabled = false;

        if (keyboardHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            UInt32 style = GetWindowLong(keyboardHandle, GWL_STYLE);
            visible = ((style & WS_VISIBLE) == WS_VISIBLE);
            disabled = ((style & WS_DISABLED) == WS_DISABLED); // ref https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065026/get-window-state-of-another-process
            log.InfoFormat("style:{0:X4} visible:{1} disabled:{2}", style, visible, disabled);
        }

        return visible && !disabled ;
    }
```

This is related to: [Show touch keyboard (TabTip.exe) in Windows 10 Anniversary edition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38774139/show-touch-keyboard-tabtip-exe-in-windows-10-anniversary-edition)

Comment: Does opening it hurt if it's already open?

Comment: Maybe `GetKeyboardWindowHandle` is failing. We don't know what it is. Also, your definition for `WS_VISIBLE` isn't quite what it should be (see [window styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632600.aspx)).

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely your `WS_VISIBLE` that is wrong. Yours is actually `WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS`, but in 15063 the keyboard window doesn't have `WS_POPUP` anymore. Anyway, you should only test for `WS_VISIBLE` which is `0x10000000`

Comment: Good call. I changed code to above but Win 10 is returning `0x84000000` which is not visible even after I open the keyboard and I see the keyboard on the screen.

Comment: @JonathanPotter there is no reliable way to "just open" it. Only toggling works. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40921638/332528

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've done some research with [Spy++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/introducing-spy-increment) . Looks like the new keyboard in Fall Creators Update (ver. 1709) is hosted by another window. This window has `Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow` class and `Microsoft Text Input Application` as its title.

The following code works for all Windows 10 versions including the new 1803 and older Windows versions as well (starting with Windows 8, I believe).

```
static class TouchKeyboard
{
    public static bool GetIsOpen()
    {
        return GetIsOpen1709() ?? GetIsOpenLegacy();
    }

    private static bool? GetIsOpen1709()
    {
        var parent = IntPtr.Zero;
        for (;;)
        {
            parent = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, parent, WindowParentClass1709);
            if (parent == IntPtr.Zero)
                return null; // no more windows, keyboard state is unknown

            // if it's a child of a WindowParentClass1709 window - the keyboard is open
            var wnd = FindWindowEx(parent, IntPtr.Zero, WindowClass1709, WindowCaption1709);
            if (wnd != IntPtr.Zero)
                return true;
        }
    }

    private static bool GetIsOpenLegacy()
    {
        var wnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, WindowClass);
        if (wnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            return false;

        var style = GetWindowStyle(wnd);
        return style.HasFlag(WindowStyle.Visible)
            && !style.HasFlag(WindowStyle.Disabled);
    }

    private const string WindowClass = "IPTip_Main_Window";
    private const string WindowParentClass1709 = "ApplicationFrameWindow";
    private const string WindowClass1709 = "Windows.UI.Core.CoreWindow";
    private const string WindowCaption1709 = "Microsoft Text Input Application";

    private enum WindowStyle : uint
    {
        Disabled = 0x08000000,
        Visible = 0x10000000,
    }

    private static WindowStyle GetWindowStyle(IntPtr wnd)
    {
        return (WindowStyle)GetWindowLong(wnd, -16);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr parent, IntPtr after, string className, string title = null);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = false)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowLong(IntPtr wnd, int index);
}
```

**Update:** I updated the answer and the code to be compatible with Redstone 4 (v1803) as well.

Comment: Excellent, Great. This is only solution that works on Windows 10 1709. Thanks.

Comment: This no longer seems to work - for me it's always returning true even if the touch keyboard is not visible on the screen. This is on Windows 10 19042.1110

Answer (score 3):

I'm using this solution, and it is working on Windows 1607, 1709 and 1803 (check the Main method below on the code):

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {

        [ComImport, Guid("D5120AA3-46BA-44C5-822D-CA8092C1FC72")]
        public class FrameworkInputPane
        {
        }

        [ComImport, System.Security.SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity,
        InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown),
        Guid("5752238B-24F0-495A-82F1-2FD593056796")]
        public interface IFrameworkInputPane
        {
            [PreserveSig]
            int Advise(
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object pWindow,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object pHandler,
                out int pdwCookie
                );

            [PreserveSig]
            int AdviseWithHWND(
                IntPtr hwnd,
                [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.IUnknown)] object pHandler,
                out int pdwCookie
                );

            [PreserveSig]
            int Unadvise(
                int pdwCookie
                );

            [PreserveSig]
            int Location(
                out Rectangle prcInputPaneScreenLocation
                );
        }


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputPane = (IFrameworkInputPane)new FrameworkInputPane();
            inputPane.Location(out var rect);
            Console.WriteLine((rect.Width == 0 && rect.Height == 0) ? "Keyboard not visible" : "Keyboard visible");
        }
    }
}
```

It uses the *IFrameworkInputPane* interface (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-iframeworkinputpane)

Comment: This approach works as of July 24th 2021 on Windows 10 Enterprise Build 19042

Answer (score 1):

I discovered yet another undocumented COM API that returns the position of the touch keyboard. It returns the bounds of the keyboard window or zeroes if the keyboard is hidden. I tested it in `Windows 8.1`, `Windows 10` and `Windows 10 Fall Creators Update` and it works fine.

Now some bad news: in all versions prior to `Fall Creators Update` it only reports accurate results if the active window and the touch keyboard are located on the same monitor. If this is not the case - the API just returns the previous cached value. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that this API was meant to be used to calculate occlusion of the touch keyboard and your app's window. (It's called inside [`Windows::UI::ViewManagement::InputPane.get_OccludedRect()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.inputpane#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_InputPane_OccludedRect) UWP API).

So if you don't care about supporting older versions or multi-monitor scenarios - use it. Otherwise I would suggest checking the Windows version and falling back to the previous method ([`GetIsOpenLegacy()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47405060/332528) from my other answer).

The API:

```
[ComImport, Guid("228826af-02e1-4226-a9e0-99a855e455a6")]
class ImmersiveShellBroker
{
}

[ComImport, Guid("9767060c-9476-42e2-8f7b-2f10fd13765c")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IImmersiveShellBroker
{
    void Dummy();
    IInputHostManagerBroker GetInputHostManagerBroker();
}

[ComImport, Guid("2166ee67-71df-4476-8394-0ced2ed05274")]
[InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
interface IInputHostManagerBroker
{
    void GetIhmLocation(out Rect rect, out DisplayMode mode);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Rect
{
    public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom;
}

enum DisplayMode
{
    NotSupported = 0,
    Floating = 2,
    Docked = 3,
}
```

Usage example:

```
// do this once:
var brokerClass = new ImmersiveShellBroker();
var broker = (IImmersiveShellBroker)brokerClass;
var ihm = broker.GetInputHostManagerBroker();
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(broker);

// now ihm reference can be cached and used later:
Rect rect;
DisplayMode mode;
ihm.GetIhmLocation(out rect, out mode);
```

Note: looks like `GetIhmLocation()` always returns `DisplayMode.NotSupported` instead of the actual `mode` prior to Windows 10.

Comment: Great. This work for Windows 10 1709 and for Windows 10 1803 too.