# How to know if keyboard is visible? (c# on win10 Fall Creator Update)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, keyboard

I'm trying to controll the Win10 virtual keyboard (should be TabTip32.exe) from a c# Windows Form Application. I need to know if the keyboard is visible or not.
The code I use is:

```
bool visible = false;
IntPtr hKeyboard = Win32.FindWindow("IPTip_Main_Window", (string)null);

if (IntPtr.Zero != hKeyboard)
{
  UInt32 style = Win32.GetWindowLong(hKeyboard, Win32.GWL_STYLE);
  visible = ((style & Win32.WS_DISABLED) != Win32.WS_DISABLED);
}
```

It worked with Anniversary Update (1607) and Creator Update (1703).
But not with [tag:Fall Creator Update] ([1709]): I can find the window but it's style is always the same.

I could find a similar way checking for a windows with name "Microsoft Text Input Application", but this work only on some PC (i still don't know why).

Can you help me?
Is there another way to do it?
I couldn't find one API to show or hide the keyboard.

Thx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine if Windows 10 Touch Keyboard is Visible or Hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47187216/determine-if-windows-10-touch-keyboard-is-visible-or-hidden)